# Android: layout for a simply menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-imagebutton

In my app I have a view with a menu in this way... but I want adapt these 4 buttons for all type of screen, that is I want that these buttons have a dynamic size... do you have any suggestions?
thanks[image]

this is my current code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.game.SplashActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/back_menu" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_1_player"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />




        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_2_player" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/challenge_bt" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/special_bt" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like so far?

Comment: LinearLayout with weight property.

Comment: I edit my question with my code...that doesn't work...

Comment: Pr38y is right, use a `LinearLayout` for these buttons. If you want e.g. their height to adjust, set the height of each button to 0dp and give the weight 1. Seems like you are using way to many wrapper layouts, just use one and put the `ImageViews` in there. You don't really the the weight-sum for the parent layout either, just give each button the weight 1.

Comment: ok it seems that it works fine... only one thing... in 7" (mdpi) and 10.1"(mdpi) these buttons remains small... why? I edit my new code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back_menu"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.game.SplashActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_1_player"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_2_player"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/challenge_bt"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/special_bt"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it works fine with imageView, but not with ImageButton